# Selecting a subset of columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using sqllite to create two tables

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);

CREATE TABLE PHONE(Id inetegr PRIMARY KEY,  PersonID integer, Number integer, 
FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES NAMES(Id)
 );
```

Then, I have written a qry to slect all people having more than 2 phones

```
select count(PersonID) as counts,Name 
from PHONE 
  INNER JOIN NAMES on NAMES.Id=PHONE.PersonID  
group by PersonID 
having counts>=2;
```

The output is like below

```
2|Tom
```

However, I dont want to print the count and just need the names, how to change my query to just print the name..

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

```
select Name from PHONE 
INNER JOIN NAMES on NAMES.Id=PHONE.PersonID  
group by Name having count(PersonID)>=2;
```

Comment: well, i shoud group it by PersonID:select Name from PHONE 
INNER JOIN NAMES on NAMES.Id=PHONE.PersonID  
group by PersonID having count(PersonID)>=2;

Comment: @Mat, yes you can do that also

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below

```
select Name from PHONE 
INNER JOIN NAMES on NAMES.Id=PHONE.PersonID  
group by Name 
having count(distinct Number)>=2;
```